# Erratic MPMoviePlayerController behaviour with M3U8 URLs

Tags: ios, video, mpmovieplayercontroller, http-live-streaming

I'm trying to play a very simple live playlist (no variants, only two segments) and can't get sane behaviour out of `MPMoviePlayerController`.

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXTINF:10.0,
1.ts
#EXTINF:10.0,
2.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

1. When `#EXT-X-ENDLIST` is missing, duration won't be shown and video will freeze at the last frame (load state "staled", playback state "playing").

   When `#EXT-X-ENDLIST` is present, duration is (expectedly) shown and video will stop at the default background with QuickTime logo (load state "stalled", playback state "paused").

   BUT, when the playlist is updated live during playback to include `#EXT-X-ENDLIST`, I can see it reloaded in web server logs, but the player does not realise the video has finished, so it will behave like in #1. This is a problem, because I cannot indicate in the UI that the stream is done.

   The problem is only with end tag, additional segments are detected correctly on reload.
2. No consistency in when the player decides it's done buffering. When I have only one segment available, playback won't start immediately, but when I have 2 or more segments, it will play all of them in a row and stall. How can I make it start playback with only 1 segment? This is a problem, because it creates additional playback start latency.
3. When there are no segments, it will be stuck with black screen in "playing" state permanently. It does not end playback, does not change state, and does not reload playlist.
4. With unfinished streams, sometimes player HUD displays blank times `--:-- o----- --:--`, sometimes `--:-- o----- Live`, seemingly whenever it feels like it.

I'm wondering whether it has some quirks in what playlists it accepts, or whether `MPMoviePlayerController` is a right tool in the first place. Can I make it behave? Should I jump straight to `AVPlayer` to have consistent playback experience?

Comment: AVPlayer is in fact used by MPMoviePlayerController, just entirely transparently to the user. I would be surprised if problems that occur while parsing the stream (as you described) would change when using AVPlayer directly instead. Have you tried [Apple's validation tool](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2235/_index.html)?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the worst of bad behaviour (#1, partly #2) was due to `.ts` segments not having their timestamps set properly. Each segment needs to have its start timestamp set to the sum of duration of all previous segments, for example:

```
start  duration
00:00  00:03
00:03  00:03
00:06  00:03
```

Whereas bad sequence would look like:

```
start  duration
00:00  00:03
00:00  00:03
00:00  00:03
```